# Access parent from child (embedded relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a class A which embeds_one class B:

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_one :b
end

class B
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :a

  def vat=(a)
  end
  def vat
    a[:name]
  end
end
```

In my class B I have a virtual attribute vat from where I want to access the parent class and its attributes - for example the name field of the document where B is embedded in. How can I access the attributes of the parent? I thought a[:name] should work since this is how I access it from outside the class- but it doesnt.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: How does it not work? Be more elaborate. Give full sequence of commands and any error if you see.

Comment: Generally, you can simply call `a.name` in any instance method of `B`. Its as simple as that.

Comment: Yes - I made a mistake. The sample above was a very reduced sample. In reality my models are created dynamically and the embedded_in was missing due to a typo. So no problem anymore accessing the parent attributes.